# Time dropdowns with date field in drupal

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-modules

In my custom module i have a date field for which I have used this code

```
$form['booking'] = array(
            '#title' => t('Booking'),
            '#type' => 'date',
            '#description' => t('Please select the date of booking'),
            '#required' => TRUE,
        );
```

but I need time fields as well in  H:i:s format  with date fields .

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

```
function mymodule_form($form, &$form_state) {
  $form = array();
  $format = 'Y-m-d H:i:s';
  $form['date2'] = array(
     '#type' => 'date_popup',
     '#title' => t('Booking'),
     '#date_format' => $format,
     ...
  );

  return $form;
}
```

Comment: I am new in drupal and I have tried date_popup but it does not show anything , don't know why thats not working .

Comment: @Ron Did you enable DatePopup module?

Comment: Is it a downladable module or drupal default one ?

Comment: @Ron it comes with Date module. You don't need to download it. Locates at Date fieldset of modules page.